# As a moderator, I would like to be able to move comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, moderator-tools

Scenario:

I have a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) where there is one answer and in the comments of the answer a third user is asking for more information to be provided in the question.

Currently there isn't a way to move the comment from the answer to the question, or to another answer for that matter.

Could we please have this functionality added?

While this is currently possible through the process that Shog describes, I was thinking something a little less complicated, easier on the eyes to see what was actually done and less confusing for people caught in the wake of the action.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is actually possible, it's just... Super non-intuitive and weird, because the tool you'd use was meant for something entirely different.

Here's the trick: you gotta convert the *answer* to a comment, and choose the option to move comments on the answer with it. This lets you select an arbitrary post as the destination - so, another answer or the question itself. Once done, you delete the comment that was created from the answer, and any comments you didn't intend to move... And then undelete the answer you "converted" and delete the comments below it that you *did* want moved.

If that sounds like a lot of work, potentially confusing and error-prone... It is. Of course, moving comments arbitrarily would be confusing and error-prone too. So this is something probably best left for very unusual circumstances.

Comment: at the end of reading that, I am thinking that I should rephrase my question from "Could we please ***have this functionality added***" to something like "*could we please have a nice way to move comments from post to post?*"

Comment: Which he has answered as well with this answer, *particularly* the end of it.

Comment: @ChristianRau I appreciate your comment, but I think you misunderstood what he wrote in that last sentence, he was only saying that based on the current functionality, not on new functionality should new functionality be implemented.

Comment: I said both, @malachi. The back end mechanics of moving comments are reasonably straightforward; a UI to make it not-confusing for mods and commenters would be much more involved. Unless this needs to be done regularly, it's probably not worth the significant investment in design to make that happen.

Comment: @Malachi I understood it as him saying it's a *good* thing it's currently confusing and error-prone since it isn't something that *should* be particularly easy and thus encouraged to do will-nilly to begin with.

Comment: @Shog9 would you add that to your Answer please?  thank you for further explaining it to me.