# Moderator "Convert to Comment" is moving comments on the answer even when that option is unselected

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

I don't know how long this has been going on as I only noticed it today when checking a question after having moved an answer via "Convert to Comment".  There is the "migrate comments on this answer as well" check box, which is by default not checked, but right now the behaviour is the same either way: *All* the comments are moved.

To be clear: Even if you do not tick the box, all the comments are posted, not just the converted answer.

Comment: Sounds like this workflow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330093/158100

Comment: @Rene My point is that (from your link:) *"you gotta...choose the option to move comments on the answer with it"*.  Right now you don't, lol.  I am sure this was not always like this as the option to *not* convert everything was a useful default and there does not seem to be a point in a tick box if leaving it unticked does the same thing as ticking it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a mod so I can't really help you in testing but I remembered that post, so at least you now have evidence that it used to work.

Comment: No repro here. I wish it would do that by default :-)

Comment: Huh.  Well, I've verified this THREE times now from two different machines (both of them via chrome, but...) using questions of my own where I've got an answer too.

Comment: Same on SOru. Comments moved even without option checked.

Comment: I can confirm this just happened to me - converted answer to comment on question, and it moved the comments from that answer onto the question also.  The check-box was left unchecked.  On GIS.SE

Comment: Also confirming that behaviour change recently. I noticed it on at least two occasions now on AU within the last week maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

As part of some code cleanup and refactoring, I moved from using a `FormCollection` in our asp.net MVC method to `bool migrateComments`.  Because I misread the original code, I thought the default behavior was true, so I made it an optional parameter `bool migrateComments = true`.  This was a foolish move because HTML forms omit unchecked checkboxes from submission, so any time it was checked, the method was called with `migrateComments = true`, and any time it was unchecked, it was called with nothing and `true` was inferred.

The funny thing here is that I completely skipped this in my tests, but I tested both cases for "Convert to edit".  I probably missed this because they checkbox appears only if comments are there and I forgot it even existed.