# Some moderator tools related to deleted comments aren't working

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-comments

Since at least 1 August, the moderator tool “show X deleted comments” leads to a 404 page. For example: on [Is the calculation of infinite sums solvable by a computer?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112325), I click “mod” then “show 7 deleted comments” then “Submit”, and I'm brought to https://cs.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/112325/ which is a 404 page, instead of the correct URL which would be https://cs.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/112325/comments.

Posting this together because it's very likely to be related, when I used the “move comments to chat” moderator tool on that post, the dialog wasn't dismissed and the animated dots at the bottom of the dialog kept flashing. But when I reloaded the page, everything had happened correctly (chatroom created, comments converted to chat messages and deleted). The same happened with https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37667 and just now with https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/112483.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331690/moderator-convert-to-comment-is-moving-comments-on-the-answer-even-when-that-o

Comment: It worked for me just now. Fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is fixed.

It's somewhat related to the issue Shog linked to in that it's part of the same project and I'm to blame, but it was caused by an entirely different mistake.

As part of a mod-menu refresh, I split our big moderator.js source file, moderator.ts, into three files, one for the mod-menu, one for the dashboard, and one for everything else.  Because everything wasn't in the same closure anymore, I had to make some decisions about dependencies, expose them or do something different.  In this case, I decided to select the comment post container with this query:

```
$(`.js-comments-container[data-post-id=${id}]:not([data-comment-context=flag])`)
```

Unfortunately, I omitted the trailing parenthesis and the selector threw an error.  Completely my bad in not testing more of the options to unearth this one, but I will partially shake my fist at the inconsistent way TypeScript compiles on my machine for *maybe* burying the issue.

Why you ended up on a non-existent page has to do with the wonky way this particular dialog works:

When you click an click submit, we have a form submit event handler that either performs a specific JavaScript action based on what you selected (like showing comments) and returns false or modifies the form's action attribute and returns true.  Because we threw an error before returning false, the the default form behavior continued uninterrupted and it submitted with the invalid URL the form starts out with.

This bug also affected the reloading aspect of "purge all comments" and "move comments to chat", but that was less noticeable because the action executed correctly, it just didn't update the page.